# Trust Relationship between this Workstation and the Primary Domain failed, but 4624 events are present

Tags: active-directory, trust-relationship

User got this error when user tried to login to his workstation.

Usually this means that computer account password in AD and on the actual workstation is out of sync for some reason. According to metadata workstation **changed its password yesterday's evening** and reports of logon problems came soon after.

However, I can read many **4624 events ("logon success")** on security log on DCs since the last attribute change for **unicodePwd** for said computer account with matching IP address and logon type 3 (network logon). In my understanding this means that computer password **match** stored in AD, otherwise it should be generating 4625 events instead. Yet user was unable to login with his password on said workstation before we've reset computer account.

So, any clues what is wrong there?

Comment: Sometimes, when a Windows computer experiences login issues, the solution is to rejoin the computer to the network and reset the Active Directory computer account during the rejoin process. This was a common occurrence at a previous job where I was responsible for over 400+ on-site employees, with 1k of them in the DACH region. Although we never determined the root cause of the problem, we always used this same solution to fix it. This method even works when using a VPN, as long as it is properly configured.

Comment: `any clues what is wrong` no. All computers change their password every 30 days. Nothing significant there.

Comment: @GregAskew: to be fair I _have_ seen a few cases when a regular machine password happened and somehow resulted in the account getting out of sync (was not sure whether it was the machine or the DC that lost the change)

Comment: `I can read many 4624 events` that cannot occur when the trust relationship is broken. Once the trust is broken, everything stops working. It is, however, a common occurrence when a backup of a host has been restored or another copy of the (virtual) host has been turned up. More rarely, It may also occur if someone were to configure another host to impersonate the identity of the affected host.

Comment: Not uncommon in scenarios where there is a separate network for testing, that temporarily becomes connected to the main production network.

Comment: Another edge case to consider would be the endpoint successfully changes its password, but then a failure on that DC resulted in the new password not being replicated to the PDC emulator. (PDCe comms aren't required for changing a computer account password). However that is rare, probably related to crappy replication and/or AD design, and AD is supposed to treat computer accounts differently and accept authentication using the previous credentials. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/password-change-processing-conflict-resolution-function